# Probability on dice roll where one value is twice the number on the other dice

Tags: probability

I am having some trouble on understanding the following problem on probability..

> A black and a red die are tossed, what is the probability that the
>   number on the red die is twice the number on the black die?

I wrote out the possible number of outcomes where the number on red die is bigger than black die as follows (first number denotes as the red die, while the second is the black die):

`{(2,1), (3,1), (4,1),(4,2), (5,1), (5,2), (6,1), (6,2), (6,3)}` but it seems that my answer is wrong as `(2,1),(4,2), (6,3)` is not part of the given event.

So why are these 3 excluded? I mean, the values on red die is twice than the value on the black die, no?

Answer (score 1):

`{(2,1),(4,2),(6,3)}` is the event that the red die shows *exactly* twice the value of the black die.   The wording of your question indicates this is what the text was after.

`{(2,1),(3,1),(4,1),(5,1),(6,1),(4,2),(5,2),(6,2),(6,3)}` is the event that the red die shows *at least* twice the value of the black die.

`{(3,1),(4,1),(5,1),(6,1),(5,2),(6,2)}` is the event that the red die shows *more than* twice the value of the black die.

Comment: Thanks for listing it all out. It sure does clears some of the doubts I have. But one question though, unless the question has the keyword `at least`, my answer should just be 3 then, right?

Comment: Yes.  A mathematics textbook *should* be worded concisely.  @dissidia.

Answer (score 0):

Tossing two dices obtains $6*6=36$ possible outcomes. {$(1,1),(1,2), ... ,(6,6)$}

Now the possible outcomes that number on the red die is twice the number on the black die is

{${(1,2),(2,4),(3,6)}$}  (assuming th first component denotes the black die and the second is red die.)

Thus the probability is $\frac{3}{36} =\frac{1}{12}$

Comment: hi there, now I am even more confused.. so `(2,1), (3,1), (4,1),(4,2), (5,1), (5,2), (6,1), (6,2), (6,3)` (first number denotes on the red die), are not part of the outcomes?

Comment: No. you must have the number  on the red die is twice the number on the black die, let the number on the red be $x$ and the number on the black die be $y$ ,so you must have $x=2y$.

Answer (score 0):

According to @GrahamKemp's correct lists 'favorable' outcomes
in a sample space with 36 points:

$P(R = 2B) = 3/36 = 0.0833333,\;$ $P(R \ge 2B) = 9/36 = 0.25,\;$ and
$P(R > 2B) = 6/36 =  0.1666667.$

I hope you understand how these probabilities are found, and why the
sum of the first and third probabilities is equal
to the second.

Here is a simulation in R of a million 2-dice experiments, with the
'long-run' proportions of each kind of outcome. Proportions agree with
probabilities to 2 or 3 places.

```
 red = sample(1:6, 10^6, rep=T)
 blk = sample(1:6, 10^6, rep=T)
 mean(red == 2*blk)
 ## 0.083475
 mean(red >= 2*blk)
 ## 0.250812
 mean(red > 2*blk)
 ## 0.167337
```

Note: `red == 2*blk` is a 'logical vector', a list of a million TRUEs and FALSEs.
The `mean` of such a vector is the proportion of TRUEs it contains.